# Exclude string from xss filter if its part of email address

Tags: xss

In my application I have set an xss filter rule like below.
**xss.filter.rule.alert=(?i)alert**
But if I enter an email address with the string 'alert' in it, the alert is getting stripped.
for example myname@alerttext.com is being stripped to myname@text.com.

How can i exclude 'alert' text if it is part of a email address.